# How to select inputs of type file that have been loaded by the user?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming you have a large number of inputs of type 'file', like so:

```
<input type="file" id="fileSomething1" />
<input type="file" id="fileSomething2" />
```

Is it possible to select all inputs of type 'file' that the user has loaded at least 1 file into?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$("input[type='file' && value!='']").length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax for chaining of multiple attribute equals selector. It should be:

```
$("input[type='file'][value!='']").length
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6wmgtq02/)**

I would also suggest you to consider using `.filter()` selector for comparing value condition.

Comment: I tested this. It does not work. The length remains the same, even after I load a file in an input. I'm looking into filter() now...

Comment: @Zesty: Added link to working demo.

Answer (score 0):

This code enable loop checking for input type file,If any of it find having value then it  would print

```js
$("#butn").on("click", function() {
  $("input[type=file").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      console.log($(this).attr('id'))
    }
  });
})

$("input[type=file").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).val() != "") {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="fileSomething1" />
<input type="file" id="fileSomething2" />
<button id="butn">click</button>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.